# Sorting date in SQLITE

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I have dates in `Java` formatted as : `"dd-MM-YYYY"`. So, I'm gonna save them into my `SQLITE` `DateBase` and after `SELECT` (`order by`) I want to get them sorted. How it's possible to save them as a `date` `type`?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but it appears you are storing your dates as varchar, with the day, month, and year appearing in that order.  This means that it will be difficult to sort as is.

Comment: `INSERT INTO your_table_name [(column1, column2, ... columnN)] 
   SELECT column1, column2, ...columnN 
   FROM table_name` is that what you need ?

Comment: @Sami Actually no, I need to convert the given date and than save them into datebase appropriately.

Comment: You time strings are not in the correct format. You need to use the ISO standard. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting is incorrect and won't allow you to sort your table by date.

If you set up the format as `"yyyy-mm-dd"` then you can simply order by `ASC` or `DESC`.

Can you simply change how Java formats your dates to begin with or will you need to convert the format?

Edit

Comment: fair enough yyyy-mm-dd then.